# Receiving the error "undefined symbol" when loading C++ dynamic library from C executable

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to write a plugin for a popular program whose code and compilation process I do not have control over. The program is written in C. However, I have written parts of my plugin in C++, since I use the QT5 library for graphics capabilities. The functions that the C program calls are written in C.

When the C program tries to load the plugin (shared library), it produces this error:

```
dlopen('build/libfoo.so') failed: build/libfoo.so: undefined symbol: _ZTV13JoystickPanel
```

`JoystickPanel` is a class in the C++ part of the program.

I've tried rewriting parts of the program in C, but the error was unaffected. I know that I could rewrite the entire program in C, but I'd rather not have to switch to another, more C-friendly GUI framework. I've also opened up `libfoo.so` in a text editor and search for `JoystickPanel`, but it appears to be mangled as `_ZN13JoystickPanel`.

Are there any compiler options or solutions that I'm missing?

Comment: C++ and C to be able to call each other need special care.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It's a specific problem and merits an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I'd forgetten to put the `#include "moc_controller.cpp"` line at the bottom of a file that needed it.

For anyone else chasing this issue while using Qt on CMake, consider making sure that the proper lines are added.

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea what `_ZN13JoystickPanel` means, since it's not apparently a valid mangled C++ name. It should perhaps be `_ZN13JoystickPanelE`, which would translate to `JoystickPanel`. That'd be symbol name for sure, but without much meaning anyway. You must have truncated something: I tried quite a bit and just can't generate an object file that would include `_ZN13JoystickPanel` as the complete symbol. It's just a prefix, there should be a "second half" attached to it - was there?

But `_ZTV13JoystickPanel` is the vtable for the `JoystickPanel` class. It's missing because you didn't provide implementations for all the virtual methods of the `JoystickPanel` class. Most likely, you didn't invoke moc properly, or forgot to compile and link its output.

You need to show a complete build script for your plugin at the very least (the `.pro` file, or `CMakeLists.txt`). You'll also need to provide a github link to your project (I presume it's open source).

The symbols you want to find in the compiled output are at least `_ZTV13JoystickPanelD#Ev` - virtual destructors, where # is a digit, `_ZTV13JoystickPanel` - the virtual method table,

Those symbols may be absent when compiled with optimization and/or LTCG, but also absent will be references to them.

You may wish to delete the build folder and rebuild your project, just to be sure. `qmake` is bad at dependency generation for the makefiles it produces, so if you use it, I suggest switching to `cmake` + `ninja`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. [Here is my `CMakeLists.txt` file](https://github.com/not-a-seagull/tasinput2/blob/cplusplus/CMakeLists.txt) (also links to the repository).

To add on: when I open the `tasinput2_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp` file, it says that no MOC files were found. I do have `Q_OBJECT` inside of my QWidget inheritors.

Comment: Do not use globbed sources. Like, ever. Just don't. They seem to work. And then they don't work. Just don't. If you have a library project, just add all the sources and headers manually to it. I mean it. I refuse to look into it any further until that is fixed ;)

Comment: @JohnNunley Also: what is the architecture and OS you're compiling this for? And the exact source of Qt you're using (e.g. a Linux distro package - include version too, or a Qt installer download, etc - be specific, imagine that I'll be following your steps exactly, because, well, I will).

Comment: I've removed the globs. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. The version of the `qt5-default` package is `5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5`. [Here is a list of every package I have with `qt` in the name](https://gist.github.com/not-a-seagull/19c12f66fe547bf2080d46ec06430c57). Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: Also, the program I'm making this for is `mupen64plus`.

Comment: Cool. I’ll see what I can figure out.

Comment: I was tinkering with the code a bit and looking into the MOC. Apparently, I forgot to add `#include "mocs_controller.cpp"` to the end of the `controller.cpp` file. That seems to have fixed the issue. Should I answer my own question with that solution?

Comment: Yes! Please answer it yourself!